# PHP rCopy Set File chMod?

Tags: php

I am using the following code to copy a folder and it's contents from location A to B.

It's works file but I have a problem with the file ownerships...it's setting the copy to Nobody

I've tried activating suPHP but my website broke so can't do that one.

Are there any work arounds?

Here is the code I'm using:

```
rcopy("$source_folder", "$target_folder");
chmod($target_folder, 0755);
chmod($target_folder.'/images', 0777);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Activating suPHP or implementing a [workaround](http://php.net/chown#91599) will be your only options.

Your site may have broken when suPHP was activated because some of your directory permissions were not set correctly.  Make sure none of your directories or files are world or group writable.  Set directories to 744, and files to 644 generally.

Check your error log for more details as to why suPHP was preventing your site from running.

Comment: It's a live website with traffic cannot play with it unless it's last resort.

Comment: Do you still have error logs available from the time when you made the switch to suPHP?  You may be able to resolve the problems before turning it back on, or use htaccess to serve a maintenance page to all users but yourself so you can test.